# How do you call a class' method in __init__?

Tags: python, constructor

## Code:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.w = 'foo'
        self.z = kwargs['z']
        self.my_function(self.z)    
    def my_function(self, inp):
        inp += '!!!'

input_args = {}
input_args['z'] = 'bar'
c = C(**input_args)
print c.z
```

## Expected Result

```
bar!!!
```

## Actual Result

```
bar
```

How do you call a class' method in **init**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify `self.z`, not `inp`:

```
def my_function(self, inp):
    self.z += '!!!'
```

Secondly strings are immutable in python, so modifying `inp` won't affect the original string object.

See what happens when `self.z` is mutable object:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.z = []
        self.my_function(self.z)    
    def my_function(self, inp):
        inp += '!!!'
        print inp
        print self.z

C()
```

**output:**

```
['!', '!', '!']
['!', '!', '!']
```

Comment: Ah! So it was a problem with my example! In my real-world problem, I'd be doing composition. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, you are not actually modifying the value of `self.z`

Try this instead

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.w = 'foo'
        self.z = kwargs['z']
        self.z = self.my_function(self.z)    

    def my_function(self, inp):
        inp += '!!!'
        return inp

input_args = {}
input_args['z'] = 'bar'
c = C(**input_args)
print c.z
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain any classmethods.

You are in fact calling the instance method which you are calling, it just doesn't do anything other than return `None`.

Also, if this is python 2.7, in general things will work better if you inherit from `object` (or some other class).

Answer (score -1):

You are correctly calling the class method, however parameters are passed by value, not by reference. If you modify `inp` in the method `my_function`, it doesn't reflect on `self.z`.

Comment: Not downvoted. But in python parameters are passed by reference. The problem is that the reference is changed when do a `+=` to strings or numbers (but list won't).

Comment: @neuront Only mutable parameters are passed by reference, immutable are passed by value. [Blair Conrad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1199/blair-conrad) has written a [extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/758165) on this topic. But you are right in the regard that I should not have generalized.

Comment: No parameters at all are passed by reference. I downvoted this because there is no class method.

Comment: @Pit The first line in the answer you link correctly states that parameters are passed by value. They are passed *only* by value.

Comment: @Marcin I should have rephrased my comment. As Blair put it, the reference to a mutable object gets passed by value. So you are correct in that regard. However, I do think that `my_function` is a class method. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Pit It's not a classmethod. What makes you think that? Go read about what a classmethod is.

Comment: @Mercin Oh, I'm sorry. I mixed up the definition of a classmethod and a module-function.

Comment: @Pit you're slightly incorrect. In both cases, (the references to) the objects are passed by value; the difference is handled by the way Python implements operators as method calls. When an object has an `__iadd__` attribute (like `list`), `a += b` will be translated to `a.__iadd__(b)`, but when that operation is performed on objects without `__iadd__`, the translation defaults to `a = a.__add__(b)`.